how to open Lua file in interpreter?
i am teaching myself off websites and i have a book coming. i am not sure what all else needs to be added to this question.
I wrote a  file Hello as the proper file suffix  and i tried using the interpreter to open the file and run it.
what do i do?
tried load file, i tried Do file, i tried open().
****do to the proper qualification check this site has i cant put the file extension or codes that i used it keeps rejecting this post, so i hope you understand what i am saying****

Show us copies of your sessions trying to open a file with Lua

You can either embed Lua into your application, run a third party application with an embedded interpeter or you install the standalone Lua interpeter on your machine and run it.
https://lua.org/start.html
Read the Lua manual. Ideally all of it but chapter 7 is about the standalone interpreter. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#7
Once you have the Lua standalone interpeter you simply run lua hello.lua from your console.
